# What is the problem when the AArch64 bl jump is greater than 128 MB

Tags: arm64

## Manual Description

```
Branches  

B 

PC relative branch ±128 MB

Conditional version B.cond (covered later) has ±1 MB range 

BL 

Similar to B (branch range ±128 MB) but also stores return address in LR (X30), hinting that this is a function call

No conditional version
```

## Questions

- Why limit the range to ±128M?
- What is the problem when the AArch64 bl jump is greater than 128 MB?

Answer (score 2):

> Why limit the range to ±128M?

A64 instructions are all 32 bits wide. 6 bits are designated to distinguishing `B` and `BL` from other instructions. The remaining 26 bits encode the (signed) jump offset. Since all instructions are 4 bytes wide, jumps only need to go to 4-byte aligned addresses, so that offset can be shifted << 2, which yields a range of `-0x8000000` to `0x7fffffc`, or ±128MiB.

> What Is the Problem When the AArch64 bl Jump Is Greater Than 128 MB?

Then you don't have enough bits in the instruction to encode the offset. You'd have to do something like `adrp`+`add`+`b(l)r`, or if even the ±4GiB offset of ADRP isn't enough, you'd probably just store the literal address of the target somewhere in the data section (where it gets rebased by the dynamic linker) and use `ldr`+`b(l)r`.